# AngularJS - How to include content to dynamically generated bootstrap nav-tabs based on certain conditions?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Here is my [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/8/) that demonstrates the problem.

I have a container div, that has a fixed height. The data that gets populated within the div comes from a list of json objects, and the size of the text content varies for each item.

So, when the content size is bigger than the height of the div, there is a huge overflow of text outside the div.

I need to place the overflown contents into a another div of same height which can be accessed through nav-tabs. The number of nav-tabs should depend of the size of the overall content.

At the moment, I'm creating nav-tabs based on the length of the list, but still I can't figure out a way to append the overflowing text into the new tab(s). How can I achieve this ? Please feel free to edit my above jsfiddle.

Also, I'm currently creating nav-tabs based on a crude calculation that depends on the length of the list, and this method is very inefficient as the number of nav-tabs should be created based on the size of the content. For example, if all the contents can fit in the first div, then one nav-tab is sufficient. If the overflow from first div can be accommodated in just one more new div, then two nav-tabs will be enough, and similarly the rest.

So, is there a way to create nav-tabs based on size of the content ?

Below is my controller that creates a list with dummy data, and then creates navtabs. The rest of my code is available on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/8/)

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.list = [];

$scope.generateList = function () {
    var tmpList = [{text:'first item',value:0,enabled:true}];

    var someText = ' - Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.' + 
    'It has roots in a   piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,' +
     'making it over 2000 years old.';

    var count = $scope.input;
    for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.input; i++) {
        var appendText = tmpList[i-1].text;
        tmpList.push({
            text: 'item' + i + someText + appendText,
            value: i,
            enabled: true
        });
    }

    $scope.list = tmpList;

    $scope.navtabs = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(tmpList.length / 5); i++) {
        $scope.navtabs.push({
            id: i,
            name: 'tab' + i
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

possible use "ui bootstrap pagination" :

add filter paginate on ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:paginate:current:5">
    <div ng-switch on = "item.value % 2">
        <div ng-switch-when="0">
            <div>Some Title - (even)
                <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.text | breakFilter"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="1">
            <div>Some Title - (odd)
                <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.text | breakFilter"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add pagination directive :

```
<pagination class="pagination" ng:show="list.length>5" total-items="list.length" page="current" boundary-links="true" max-size="7" num-pages="numPages" rotate="false">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using pagination before, but the problem I have is that the number of 'pages' or 'tabs' should depend on the content of the data, and not the count, because content of one item can be considerably bigger or smaller than the other. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be great if you could update my fiddle and show a working example of correctly using pagination in my case.

Comment: to keep the system tab: 
should be created for each element a tab and the associated element to the tab